# How to install iOS 9.1 simulator in Xcode Version 7.1.1 (7B1005)

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode7, ios9.1

What is the latest version of simulator that is available?

How can I install iOS 9.1 simulator into my Mac?

The below screenshot shows that iOS 9.0 simulator is the recent one.
[image: Xcode Preferences -> Downloads]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Goto Xcode -> Window -> **Devices** (Shortcut: ⇧⌘2)

[image: Xcode Devices]

2. Click on **+** (on bottom left corner) and **Add Simulator**.

[image]

3. Choose Device type & iOS Version as iOS 9.1, and then click **Create** button.

[image]

Comment: This is the best answer. Thank you Valamburi.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 7.1.1 comes bundled with the iOS 9.1 Simulator SDK and Runtime.  You do not need to take any extra steps to install it like you do for the older runtimes.